# Download button on the left of the search-bar [is this PWA feature?]

Tags: google-chrome, download, progressive-web-apps

is there any start point where I can find on how/what required to implement the download button for my website to be downloadable like this in the attached image - thanks
[image]

Comment: See https://web.dev/learn/pwa/